# Are there any use to limit yourself to HTTP1.0?

Tags: http, explorer

I've been put in charge of building some tools to help end-user test why their browser might not work with a website.

Among the reason I was given to why it might not work there was this "require HTTP1.1" line. I've looked through most browser options and only IE (version 6 and up, **even 9**) allow you to disable HTTP1.1.

Are there any use to be able to restrict yourself to http1.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, no, you don't ever want the client to only offer HTTP/1.0, as this will slow things down.

Some *servers* will intentionally use HTTP/1.0 with a Keep-Alive header on some responses because certain browsers (e.g. IE6/IE7) will allow more parallel connections for HTTP/1.0 (four) vs. HTTP/1.1 (two).

Comment: Thanks! Sounds better than my "_We got client who still use browser that only manage http1.0, so we got to test it_".