# Why is Connection: keep-alive still being specified in http headers (isn't it deprecated)?

Tags: http, keep-alive, http-1.1, http-1.0

According to "HTTP: The Definitive Guide", using

```
Connection: keep-alive
```

to specify a persistent connection is deprecated in HTTP/1.1, since HTTP/1.1 specifies that connections are persistent by default and must be closed manually by sending

```
Connection: close
```

Thus, my simple assumption is that "Connection: keep-alive" shouldn't really be used anymore. However, it still seems alive and well. For example, keep-alive is being returned in the following query:

```
curl -I https://foursquare.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/0.8.52
Date: Thu, 11 Aug 2011 21:15:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Thu, 11 Aug 2011 21:15:45 UTC
Set-Cookie: XSESSIONID=w19~kqtn4bpqmfq51p8qolstpk6ti;Path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: LOCATION=49.25::-123.13330078125::Hockeytown::CA;Path=/;Secure
Set-Cookie: bbhive=OQ32XATE0OQAEVCY0IVSWUDPQ1A2GT
Content-Length: 38815
Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
```

My question is: **Why is Connection: keep-alive still being specified in HTTP headers?**

A corollary question is: **Are there still (clients, servers, proxies, etc) that still only speak HTTP/1.0 and its variants, or are most such entities on HTTP/1.1 as of 2011?**

Here are my working hypotheses:

1) HTTP/1.0 is no longer in use, b/c that was "many years" ago

2) Given (1), keep-alive *shouldn't* be used anymore, but *is* purely for vestigial reasons (that is, certain technologies haven't bothered to remove it, or keep it around as voodoo code, etc.)

If (1) is incorrect, and HTTP/1.0 is still in use, then sure it seems plausible to keep using keep-alive, despite follow-up questions on HTTP 1.0-1.1 interop.

Thanks in advance for any insights shared!

Comment: This is an incorrect hypothesis: "HTTP/1.0 is no longer in use." There's a fair number of junky HTTP/1.0-only proxy servers in the world. But yes, I believe it's mostly there because it's voodoo.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I just found your related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6257470/are-there-any-use-to-limit-yourself-to-http1-0/6257911#6257911 feel free to upgrade your comment to a full answer!

Answer (score 14):

HTTP/1.0 have no headers like `Connection`, but there is many different implementation of HTTP/1.0 and HTTP/1.1.

so `Connection: keep-alive` is used  '**Just in case**'